# How to add row borders and zebra stripes (row striping) to datatables DT in R?

Tags: html, r, datatables, border

I would like to know the proper way to add [row borders](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes) *styling* and [zebra stripes](http://datatables.net/reference/option/) *option* to [datatables](http://datatables.net) created with the package [DT](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/) in R.

Simple starter example:

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris)
```

Simple example with options:

```
datatable(head(iris, 20), options = list(
  columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 4)),
  pageLength = 5,
  lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15, 20)
))
```

*Not sure why I received a down vote?  Please let me know if anything is unclear or how to improve this question.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the `stripe` and `row-border` class to the table container:

```
library(DT)
library(htmltools)
datatable(
  head(iris, 20),
  container = tags$table(
    class="stripe row-border",
    tags$thead(tags$tr(lapply(colnames(iris), tags$th)))
  )
)
```

This will create the `table` container with both classes and the styling feature will be applied. You can add any other styling from the link you posted.

Comment: How to stripe columns but not row?