# stripes for DT::datatable

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I am hoping to get a repeated pattern for the [datatable](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/) in the code below where 3 rows are colored followed by 3 in white, then again colored...  Can somebody please help me with code for that?

Also, in my Shiny app there are several tables each of which may need different styles.  Would appreciate an answer which shows how the style can be tied to a particular table so that I can use that to develop other styles for the other tables.

```
require(shiny)
require(DT)

MkDF <- function(nr) { data.frame(value1=1:nr, value2=runif(nr)) }

server <- function(input, output) {
    ds <- MkDF(15)
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable({ 
        DT::datatable(ds, options=list(info=F, searching=F, paging=F),
            container= htmltools::tags$table(class="stripe row-border"),
            colnames=c("My Value1","My Value2")) %>% formatRound(2,2)
    })
}

ui <- shinyUI(
    navbarPage("Example",
        tabPanel("DT", fluidRow( column(offset=2, width=4, DT::dataTableOutput('tbl') ) ) )
    )
)

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using the following rowCallback funtion:

```
DT::datatable(ds,
 options=list(info=F, searching=F, paging=F,
 rowCallback=JS(
  'function(row,data) {
     if($(row)["0"]["_DT_RowIndex"] % 6 <3) 
            $(row).css("background","orange")
   }'))) %>% formatRound("value2",2)
```

Basically you can get the DT row index `$(row)["0"]["_DT_RowIndex"]` and use the modulo `%` operator to color rows.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  In my Shiny app, I have 10+ datatables each using formatRound/formatPercentage on multiple columns.  Also the DT implementation (see [link](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/blob/master/R/format.R)) handles NAs the way I would prefer.  Is it possible to get a solution which works with those format function?

Comment: it actually works fine with the `formatRound` function, I edited the code

Comment: looks like the data argument is required for the format functions to work

Comment: do you know if there is a way to set the [display](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes) options from Shiny? Thx.

Comment: you can look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517919/how-to-add-row-borders-and-zebra-stripes-row-striping-to-datatables-dt-in-r)

Comment: Thanks.  That approach seems to hide colnames when they are specified.  I am modifying the original example to show the same.  Comment out the container line and colnames are fine.