# DT::datatable customization stripes

Tags: css, r, dt

The DT package within R provides an amazing set of functions to create interactive tables within your Rmarkdown documents or Shiny Apps. The vignette / help page is very informative and will help with most problems. See [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/)

However, when it comes down to changing the color of the stripes, I'm struggling to find a straightforward solution.

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553771/stripes-for-dtdatatable), I came with the following to change the color of the stripes:

```
markets_list <- c("GC=F","SI=F","PL=F","CL=F","BZ=F","^TNX","^TYX","^VIX")
Now_Quotes <- getQuote(markets_list) %>% 
dplyr::mutate(names = c("Gold","Silver","Platinum","Oil","Brent","Treas10Y","Treas30Y","VIX"))

datatable(Now_Quotes[,c(9,2)],
rownames = FALSE,
colnames = "",
options = list(dom = 't',bSort=FALSE,
columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = c(0,1))),
rowCallback=JS('function(row,data) {if($(row)["0"]["_DT_RowIndex"] % 2 == 1) $(row).css("background","#737373")}'),
initComplete = JS("function(settings, json) {$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#252525', 'color':     '#fff'});}")))
```

Clearly this does not seem to be the right way, as it should be possible to change the colors based on simple css rules. Can someone please provide the right way. Thanks

Comment: could you provide a reproducible example. You don't provide Now_Quotes

Comment: Absolutely, good point. Now_Quotes added.